# Harmonic series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

Is there a sequence that converges to zero such that the series over the product of every summand of the harmonic series with the appropriate element of the sequence is not convergent?

Comment: Do you mean a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n \to 0$ and $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent?

Comment: Could you write this more explicitly out in symbols?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_n\Pi_{k}^{n}a_k$ is convergent?

Comment: It's good to express the question only literary but I suggest you explain it more by mathematical symbols.

Comment: It is the equation given by Simeon that I am looking for. The only difference, the series is supposed to be divergent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n = 1/(\ln(n+1))$. Then $a_n \to 0$ but
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n+1)}$$
diverges. This can be seen using the integral test.